# Microphone have sound drops, windows 10

Tags: microphone

My problem is that sometimes the sound from the mic, at whoevers hears me (mainly zoom) is low, almost zero for half a second. other than that is great.

I bought 2 new mics so i believe its not a hardware problem, since 1 goes to the little hole, the other to usb

Comment: Does your computer offer any 'noise cancelling' features or software that you could try disabling?  Have you tried reproducing it with an offline product like Audacity in case the audio drop is related to your internet connection not your sound hardware?

Comment: No noise canceling things
will try offline